# Designing a general database interface in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns

I'm creating a small framework for my web projects in PHP so I don't have to do the basic work over and over again for every new website. It is not my goal to create a second CakePHP or Codeigniter and I'm also not planning to build my websites with any of the available frameworks as I prefer to use things I've created myself in general.

I have had no problems in designing and coding the framework when it comes to parts like the core structure, request handling, and so on, but I'm getting stuck with designing the database interface for my modules.

I've already thought about using the MVC pattern but found out that it would be a bit of an overkill for my rather small project(s).

So the exact problem I'm facing is how my frameworks modules (`viewCustomers` could be a module, for example) should interact with the database.

- Is it (still) a good idea to mix in SQL directly into PHP code? (Would be "old way": `mysql_query( 'SELECT firstname, lastname(.....)`)?
- How could I abstract a query like the following?

  ```
  SELECT firstname, lastname FROM customers WHERE id=X
  ```

Would MySQL "helper" functions like

`$this->db->customers->getBy( 'id', $x );`

be a good idea?

I'm not really sure because they tend to become useless when dealing with more complicated queries like the pretty much trivial one above.

- Is the "Model" pattern from MVC my only real option to solve this?
- What do you currently use to solve the problems shown above?

Comment: "... as I prefer to use things I've created myself in general" ... then that is something to work on. seriously. you'll do yourself, your colleagues and your customers a great favour.

Comment: back2dos: I'm creating a framework for my rather small web-projects and also a bit for fun and educational purpose. If I have already built everything myself and it all works together quite well, why should I "force in" some ORM now?

Comment: If you are very lucky, you'll end up with a buggy, functionally inferior clone of CakePHP. What the world needs is yet another PHP wrapper. Right.

Comment: When I first built my ORM and then ported my code to it I couldn't believe it. I deleted hundreds of lines of code from my models that just wan't needed anymore. Everything is so much smaller now. Of course, my ORM was only one file in size. I wouldn't say the same thing about some of those wasteful +500kb libraries out there.

Comment: Seva Alekseyev: One reason why I'm doing this is that there are things I hate about CakePHP. Also it is not like all of the frameworks out there are anything near to perfect. Second: Did you miss the part in my comment where I mentioned the words *educational* and *fun*? Third: Why "the world"? I'm not planning on spreading or praising it as if it were the new jesus framework.

Comment: @lamas: you might be suffering from the 'Not invented here' syndrom. A syndrom I also suffer from, from time to time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here

Comment: Somehow it seems more and more like if someone asks a question on SO that is not answerable in one word he is likely to get a free psychological analysis (And I mean this). It is not like I'm only using things I've come up myself, or do you see me uploading my own, better SO clone right now?  fireeyedboy: No, I'm not suffering from the "Not Invented Here" syndrome. **I just don't want to blow up my project with 2 to 5MB of Doctrine ORM now**

Comment: @lamas: I was just trying to point out a possibility. I didn't mean to offend you. I thought you might be interested in reading about it, if you didn't know about it yet. And btw: the "syndrom" thing is not ment that literally of course.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Don't worry, you haven't offended me. I just had to state (not pointed at you) why I'm doing the whole thing (re-invention of the framework or database interface in particular) as people tend to ask me why all the time.

Comment: The title is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need speed, then use raw queries (but you should really use PDO with [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)).

If you want something more OOP, you can —as you suggest it— design this with helpers.

Once, I've designed something similar which had the following concept:

1. DB connection/handler classes (handling multi-connections to different databases and different servers such as MySQL, Oracle, etc.);
2. A class per action (ie. SELECT, DELETE, etc.);
3. Filter classes (eg. RangeFilter);

The code looked something like this:

```
$select = new Select('field1', 'field2', );
$result = $select->from('myTable')
                 ->addFilter(SQLFilter::RangeFilter, 'field2')
                 ->match(array(1, 3, 5))
                 ->unmatch(array(15, 34))
                 ->fetchAll();
```

It's a simple example of how you can build it.

You can go further and implements automated handling of table relations, field type check (using introspection on your tables), table and field alias support, etc.

It might seem to be a long and hard work, but actually, it won't take you that much time to make all these features (≈1 month).

Comment: It's been years that I haven't touched PHP, so I can't tell if there is any now, but back in that time (2010!) there was no such a framework. But I've heard that Laravel has something like this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Comment: Nice, might be useful

Answer (score 6):

I believe you just want to get access to your DB from your module. I'd avoid using mysql_query directly from the code. Rather, going for simple model with abstracted DB access would be easy and straight-forward.

For example, you can have a file like models/Customers.php with this code:

```
<?php

class Customers {

    public function getById($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE id='$id'";
        $res = $DB::getRow($sql);
        return ($res);
    }
}
```

I am assuming some kind of DB helper is already instantiated and available as $DB. [Here](http://ajaxray.com/blog/simple-php-pdo-wrapper-light-static-easy-to-use) is a simple one which uses PDO.

Now, you should include this in your module and use the following way:

```
<?php

include_once "models/Customers.php";

$customers = new Customers();
$theCustomer = $customers->getById(intval($_REQUEST['cust_id']));


echo "Hello " . $theCustomer['first_name']
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

have you looked into http://www.doctrine-project.org/ or other php orm frameworks (zend_db comes to mind)?

Comment: Do you mean I should look at how they are made/work or use them instead?

Comment: using them. reinventing them once again is in my opinion wasted time. 

personally i really like zend frameworks way. you write your own app / frameworks, but plug in some of their modules for specific tasks.

Comment: The problem is how much memory these suck-up. PHP isn't built to load so many files and classes each request. So you have a trade-off between needing strong servers or easy coding.

Comment: Doctrine and others are highly discouraged by the authors of "High Performance MySQL" http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/

Comment: as xeoncross already said - it always comes down to productivity/security vs. raw performance ...
i did by the way not find any article generally discouraging the use of orm's on mysqlperformanceblog.com
ah, and apc as well as docrtine's way of 'compiling' everything into one file also helps

Answer (score 2):

Three tips:

- Use Stored Procedures (so you can separate the php from the db)
- Use PDO/[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for prepared statements `CALL NEWS_LIST(?, ?)`
- Use a Static Class for your DB.  Allows you to access it within any module.

Comment: +1: PDO, PDO, rah rah rah.  PDO, PDO, shish-boom-bah!  (Sorry, bored at work)

Comment: using a static class for DB is not much better than just using mysql_query. global mutable objects (as a static DB class is) are bad style because they are usually the source of very high coupling.

Comment: High Coupling?  I seriously doubt this.  A static custom DB class using stored procedures would allow you to utilize a DB between all modules while maintaining the ability to change your underlying database service (mysql, postgres) or add caching (memcache) without modifying the modules. Which creates lower coupling.

Comment: I quote: "Allows you to access it within any module." This introduces a dependancy between "any module" and the DB class. A dependancy that should and can easily be injected. this way, "any module" is tightly coupled with the DB class. if you then want to introduce some of the mentioned optimizations/customizations or things as sharding, you'll end up butchering the DB class as well. abstracting everything to a driver-per-class relation is the least you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Raw SQL is still the winner for me, I like to control what I send to the server (for cases like index usage, complex JOIN clauses and etc) so I generally stay away from helper functions.

You should use PDO which already provides a lot of power and if that's not enough, you can extend that (possibly with your own functions, such as checking for hits on Memcached/APC before actually querying the database). You can also extend the class to implement your own SQL functions like:

```
function getUser($user_id) {
    return $this->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . (int) $user_id);
}
```

Of course that, from the model you should still be able to send:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . (int) $user_id);
```

and get the same result. The functions should act merely as a shortcut and the extended class should not be included with the framework as it will be site-dependant.

The MVC pattern will fit nicely into this because you can use the database merely as a driver and your model can then transform the data into what you need. It's not hard to create a simple MVC structure and it will bring you benefits later.

Comment: Database abstraction is a good idea, however PDO is just one way of approaching the problem. PHP also comes with dbx_ out of the box. Then there's ADOdb, ORM, metabase....But I agree that there's nothing to be gained and a lot to be lost by trying to abstract the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You sound like me. Have you seen http://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc and the one file ORM in http://github.com/Xeoncross/database? Dig through my code and I think you will find what you're looking for.

The solution is to use the full raw power of some queries - while still allowing ORM and query builders (like codeigniter's AR) for other things.

Both are good.

Answer (score 1):

Not that i know the definitive answer (nor do i think it exists), but i thought i can just share what i have here. I use my own db 'framework', lightweight (~1000 lines currently) and easy to use. My main goal was to simplify the use of sql, not to 'hide' it from the programmer (me:). Some examples:

```
 // row() is 'query' + 'fetch' in one
 $user = $db->row("select * from users where id=25");

 // the same, injection safe
 $user = $db->row("select * from users where id=?", $_GET['id']);

 // ? placeholders are smart
 $someUsers = $db->rows("select * from users where id IN(?)", array(1, 2, 10));

 // ...and even smarter
 $data = array('name' => 'Joe', 'age' => 50);
 $id = 222;
 $db->exec("update users set ?a where id=?", $data, $id);

 // 'advanced' fetch functions
 $topNames   = $db->vlist("select name from users order by name limit 10");
 $arrayOfIds = $db->nlist("select id from users where age > 90");

 // table() returns a Table Gateway
 $db->table('users')->delete('where id=?', 25);

 // yes, this is safe
 $db->table('users')->insert($_POST);

 // find() returns a Row Gateway object
 $db->table('users')
     ->find('where name=?', 'Joe')
     ->set('status', 'confirmed')
     ->save();
```

Comment: I became a fan of your code when I saw _array and other bits on your site. Any chance you might post the above too?

Comment: hey, thanks. This is pretty much work in progress, and i don't think i can release any ready to use code anytime soon. An outdated version can be found here http://code.google.com/p/mria/source/browse/trunk/yo/db.inc.php
let me know if you have any questions/suggestions about this.

Answer (score 0):

Understand this: database interaction is a solved problem.

So unless you *really* want to do it a) for the experience or b) because you're OCD and want to know every character of the code you'll be using, then I'd choose an existing solution.

And there are many: PEAR::MDB2, Zend::Db, Creole, Doctrine, Propel, just to name a few.

Comment: i wouldn't say database interaction is a solved problem, especially through ORM's. thats why all ORMs allow you to directly query the database instead of offering a complete abstraction from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come off the "helper functions" path and the one thing that bugged me was that I continued adding functions in one file which grew and grew with identical or similar or defunct functions. I think the line count was at 600 and that is way to much for a single file in my opinion. This has not put me off the idea but I'll be more organised for the next trek. I'll probably split the db functions into multi files according to the db operation (select, insert etc...).

So my advice is to go try the "helper functions" and be as organized as you can.

Also, I used PDO for the first time and quite liked it. Its not as low tech as the mysql() functions or as bloat tech like some we could mention but won't. I'll be using PDO again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are many different opinions on this topic and as I haven't found a really satisfying answer here yet and the bounty is nearly over, I'll just write what I have come up in the last days after some trial and error:

I'm using a singleton MySQL class to handle the connection and the very basic queries as well as errors that may occur.

Single pages like `/users/show/1` (using mod_rewrite) don't use raw SQL but some kind of lightweight ORM that works like in the following example:

```
$user = $this->db
             ->users
             ->getBy( 'id', $id );
```

`$this->db` is an instance of a Database Abstraction class with a `__get( $tableName )` method. Accessing the undefined `users` property then triggers it. The rest explains itself; A query is formed from the arguments passed to `getBy( )` (SQL escaping is also handled by it) and its results are returned as an array.

I haven't finished the whole idea yet, but adding a new user to the database could look like the following:

```
$user = $this->db
             ->users
             ->new;
$user->id = 2;
$user->name = 'Joe';
$user->save( );
```

As I said the concept isn't really completed and may have (huge) flaws in it. Yet I think that it may be easier to write, more secure and easier to maintain than plain MySQL.
Some other good sides of the whole "thing" would be that it is small, therefore rather fast and also pretty straightforward.

I know that this can't compete with the extremely powerful ORMs and frameworks already out there but I'm still creating this for some reasons mentioned in one of my comments above.

Comment: Using a MVC like micromvc would allow `/users/show/1` to call `User::show($id) {}` in which you could then place `$user = new User($id);`

Answer (score -4):

If you do plan on making a database class it may be an idea looking into making it a singleton, allowing you to use it without declaring it/creating it, as...

```
global $db;
$db = new db;
$db->query ('... sql ...');
```

is kinda redundant when you can do

```
db::query ('... sql ...');
```

I have a set of SQL functions that I use on a near regular basis to reduce what used to be a multi-line escaped lot of SQL to a single call, for example:

```
get_element ($table, $element, $value, $column='id');
get_row ($table, $value, $column='id');
```

So if you just want to get the name from a table 'customers' where the id is 4 you:

```
$name = db::get_element ('customers', 'name', 4);
```

There are also accompanying functions query_element and query_row, where you just pass it an SQL string and it returns a single element/row.

Along with the functions for insert/update, e.g.

```
$array = array (
    'name' => 'bob jones',
    'age' => 28
);
$insert_id = db::insert_array ('customers', $array);

$customer_details = db::get_row ('customers', $insert_id);

$customer_details['age'] = 30;

db:update_array ('customers, $customer_details);
```

Would create a new row, pull the details back out, update the age, then re-write it to the database.

Creating custom SQL access modules on a per-table basis is generally a mistake I have always found - it's better to just generically query the database using sensible functions.

If you do have to use anything with complex joins then it is always best to create function for it getCustomerInfo () for example, but if you just want a generic table value lookup making lots of custom methods just increases the chances of mistakes in one of them.  Plus escaping data is very important - if you can use non-sql as much as possible and funnel it through a few core functions you can ensure everything is properly escaped fairly easily.

If you want to look at my custom database class let me know.

Comment: Singletons are bad, slow and especially very painful if you ever need to extend your database class or get the information from somewhere else since you're hard coding the class name all over your code. An abstract class or interface + passing along the database object where it's needed would be a much better solution.